# Convert base64 string to blob and upload it to REST API using PHP

Tags: php, rest, file-upload, upload

I need to upload a file (actually, it's a base64 string that is retrieved from another REST API) to a REST API that will accept blob as file content. In javascript, what I need to do is convert that base64 string to blob data, and pass it to a FormData and post it to the API endpoint.

I just don't know how to do that with PHP, using GuzzleHttp Client.

I hope someone with PHP skill can show me how to do that in PHP. I searched on Google but didn't seem to find a solution for me so far.

Thank you so much.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php will start you off

Comment: And I don't know guzzle specifically but I'd bet [one of these](https://www.google.com/search?q=guzzle+post+binary+data) will sort out the next step

Comment: " In javascript, what I need to do is convert that base64 string to blob data, and pass it to a FormData and post it to the API endpoint. I just don't know how to do that with PHP" Is this a javascript question or a PHP question?

Comment: @ADyson I found that file_get_contents is used to get the binary content of the file. In my case, I don't have the file, just its base64. Will base64_decode convert my base64 to binary content to pass to the request body?

Comment: @tala9999 well did you read the documentation for that function via the link I provided? What does it say about it?

Comment: @ADyson it says "Decodes data encoded with MIME base64" and I'm just not sure base64_decode(base64string) does the same as file_get_contents(filepath)?

Comment: Carry on reading. It also says _"Returns the decoded data or false on failure. The returned data may be binary"_. You can also [have a look around](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+base64_decode+binary)

Comment: `I'm just not sure base64_decode(base64string) does the same as file_get_contents(filepath)`...no, it definitely doesn't. One of them decodes a base64 string from base64 back into its original form, and the other one gets data from a file (any file, not just binary files) and puts it into a variable (without doing any transformation). They are completely different - and intentionally so. Trying to compare them doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a rough and simple idea... i added as much comments i could to make it understandable... Hope this works out for you!

```
$base64String = 'your_base64_encoded_data_here'; // base64 string
//decode the base64 string and write it to a temporary file:
$decodedData = base64_decode($base64String);

$tempFilePath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'upload');
//replace sys_get_temp_dir() with your custom dir if you want to change

file_put_contents($tempFilePath, $decodedData);

//or use fwrite 
//fwrite(fopen($tempFilePath,"w+"),$decodedData);
```

Use Guzzle to create a request and upload the file:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\MultipartStream;

$apiUrl = 'https://your_api.com/upload'; // replace with your api endpoint

$client = new Client();

// prepare data for multipart/form-data
$multipart = new MultipartStream([
    [
        'name'     => 'file', // form field name
        'contents' => fopen($tempFilePath, 'r'),
        'filename' => 'uploaded_file' // file name
    ]
]);

// create a psr-7 request object
$request = new Request('POST', $apiUrl, ['Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' . $multipart->getBoundary()], $multipart);

// send request
$response = $client->send($request);

// final response
echo $response->getBody();

// delete the temporary file
unlink($tempFilePath);
//Or move to a a folder and schedule a cronjob to clean up the folder
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the code. My code needs to run in Fusio (Open Source API Management) so I think I don't have the option to convert and save base64 string to a file. Do you know another way to feed $multipart's content with something converted from base64 string?

Comment: For my case, when I tried to replace `'contents' => fopen($tempFilePath, 'r')` by `'contents' => base64_decode($base64String)`, the file can be uploaded to the REST API as expected. So I'll mark your post as the answer. Thank you so much for everyone's help.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved the problem...